# Sharepoint how to Get context info. using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am developing the website in that i have to fetch the share point
   list details. when i try in the Google postman its working fine. But
   when i try in Javascript i faced the 401 issue.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: “host / sites / _api / contextinfo ",
           beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication ", "Basic " + btoa(“username” + ": " + “password”))
           },   
            success: function (msg){
              console.log(msg);   
            }    
  }); 
}
```

Please help me how to give the share point user details in
   javascript.

Thanks  Sundar D.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing AppParts, then this is probably one of the many prefer patterns: `var ctxApp = new SP.ClientContext("/");`  You could probably just do `var ctxApp = new SP.ClientContext();` if generally get Context information.

in regards to doing JSON/REST querying there is a little more to it:

This is what i used to get a RequestExecutor information, but should get you the idea of how to do this in SharePoint's JavaScript implementation:

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor("/");
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('tblTestList')/items?@target='" + qsHostUrl + "'&select=BdcIdentity,value",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: getListDataRESTSuccess,
    error: getListDataRESTError
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay GoldBishop